# When I use mockImplementationOnce, the new function doesn't get the parent function's args

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, mocking

I have these 2 following methods, which I created a test using jest to the one called *removerFromDb*

```
initializeData = async (collectionName) => {
    getSomeDataFromDatabase()
    this.#data = data;
}

removerFromDb = async (collectionName, _id) => {
    await database(async (db) => {
        const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
        await collection.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(_id) });
    });
    this.initializeData(collectionName);
}
```

my test looks like that:

```
const data = require('../data/testingData.json');

it('Should remove item from list', async () => {
  
  let dataCopy= data;
  database
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      dataCopy= dataCopy.filter((item) => item._id != _id);
    })
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => dataCopy);
  await DataManager.removerFromDb("", 1); // the second param serves as _id
  expect(DataManager.getData().length).toEqual(5);
});
```

Now, if you take a look at removerFromDb, you can see that it accept a second parameter named _id. But in my test when I call the method with 1 the mockImplementationOnce function I created doesn't get the value, instead it gets undefined. I found a way to make it work by doing this:

```
  database
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      const _id = 1; // notice I added this line
      replicatedData = replicatedData.filter((item) => item._id != _id);
    })
```

But it's less ideal and I don't understand why I'm not getting the value I sent through the parent function *removerFromDb*.

Is there any way to do it? Why isn't it working the first way?